# PHP explode uppercase words

Tags: php, explode, uppercase, words

how I explode in PHP uppercase words?
Like:

```
$text = "HELLO world FROM BRAZIL";
$up = explode(' ',$text);
($up[0] = HELLO, $up[1] = world, $up[2] = FROM BRAZIL)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `explode()`, try `preg_split()`:

```
$up = preg_split('/\s([^A-Z]+)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AKboksmTZt3r4TDn)

Answer (score 3):

You need to explode the string as a whole, then loop through the array and test with [`ctype_upper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php).

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/iqa5-2pn7)

```
$text = "HELLO world FROM BRAZIL";
$up = explode(' ',$text);

foreach($up AS $value){
    if (ctype_upper($value)) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "ThisIsA STRING"
echo preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/','$1 $2', $str)
This Is A STRING
```